# Detect if string contains javascript tags using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, pattern-matching

I am  trying to create a very simplistic XSS detection system for a system I am currently developing. The system as it stands, allows users to submit posts with javascript embedded within the message. Here is what I currently have:-

`var checkFor = "<script>";`

`alert(checkFor.indexOf("<script>") !== -1);`

This doesn't really work that well at all. I need to write code that incorporates an array which contains the terms I am searching for `[e.g - "<script>","</script>","alert("]`

Any suggestions as to how this could be achieved using JavaScript/jQuery.

Thanks for checking this out. Many thanks :)

Comment: Instead of you creating a simplistic XSS detection system, why not use a complex XSS detection system made by someone else?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - Thankyou for replying. Could you please recommend one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing characters is a very fragile way to avoid XSS.  (There are dozens of ways to get `<` in without typing the character -- like `&#60;`  Instead, HTML-encode your data.  I use these functions:

```
var encode = function (data) {
    var result = data;
    if (data) {
        result = $("<div />").html(data).text();
    }
};
var decode = function (data) {
    var result = data;
    if (data) {
        result = $("<div />").text(data).html();
    }
};
```

Comment: You commented that my answer will "run" tags because it assigns to innerHTML, yet your answer does the same. It's hardly an encode/decode operation since any tags will be stripped when getting the data, the result of *decode* is not guaranteed to be the same as what was passed to *encode*.

Comment: Intriguing, you're right.  In spite of the fact that the div in question isn't in the DOM, it does tend to run `data` passed into encode.  That's a pretty big fail.   And you're right, there are strings you could pass into encode that wouldn't make a safe round-trip with decode.  Probably you don't want to persist said strings though.

Comment: I stumbled upon a good reference for this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding which also notes that a round-trip won't produce identical results but more than likely you're ok with this.

Answer (score 0):

As Explosion Pills said, if you're looking for cross–site exploits, you're probably best to either find one that's already been written or someone who can write one for you.

Anyway, to answer the question, regular expressions are not appropriate for parsing markup. If you have an HTML parser (client side is easy, server a little more difficult) you could insert the text as the innerHTML of an new element, then see if there are any child elements:

```
function mightBeMarkup(s) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerHTML = s;
  return !!(d.getElementsByTagName('*').length);
}
```

Of course there still might be markup in the text, just that it's invalid so doesn't create elements. But combined with some other text, it might be valid markup.

Comment: This will correctly identify that there was tags in your string, but it will also run them first.

Comment: It won't "run" tags. Assigning to the innerHTML property doesn't execute scripts which seems to be the main issue. Elements with a src attribute shouldn't be an issue either.

Answer (score -1):

The most effective way to prevent xss attacks is by replacing all <, > and & characters with 
`&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;`.

There is a javascript library from OWASP. I haven't worked with it yet so can't tell you anything about the quality. Here is the link: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_JavaScript_Readme